# should i compile a whole kernel with only one lib file change

Tags: kernel, lib

I am doing some experiments and have changed /lib/netlink.c file by adding a printk() function. And now I would like to see this in dmesg.

So the question is, do I have to compile and install the whole kernel, or there is some other method which would not take so much time?

Comment: Which kernel version do you use? Don't see `lib/netlink.c` in any of them. In general, if modified file is compiled into the kernel, you need to recompile whole kernel for changes have an effect. If modified file is compiled into some kernel module, it is sufficient to recompile this module.

Comment: It is 4.12.0-rc6. I have downloaded it from kernel.org. Thanks for help, I should compile the whole kernel.